# Android selector color

Tags: android, colors, spinner

I customize a spinner and use as a background for each dropdown line an xml selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#FF8106"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF8106"/>
    <item android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
</selector>
```

But the colors look awful they are very dark.
How can i set those colors to look like suppose to be.

Comment: You should define your colours in separate values file.

Comment: giving detail or screenshot(how you want to see your row) will help us to guide you.

Comment: I change the code. So in class file instead of setBackgroundColor i use setBackgroundResource and on the xml file i use android:drawable instead android:color. This way i fixed and works fine. Thanks all for support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the code. So in class file instead of setBackgroundColor i use setBackgroundResource and on the xml file i use android:drawable instead android:color. This way i fixed and works fine.